# Not understanding some derivatives for e (ML error function)

Tags: partial-derivative

In an Udacity machine learning class it is showing the following simplification.

\begin{align}
\sigma'(x) & = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \\ 
           & = \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} \\
           & = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \cdot \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} \\
           & = \sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))
\end{align}

(Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ihZ2.gif)

I am not following the line 1 to 2 and line 3 to 4. For line 1 -> 2, shouldn't that now be 1 / ( - (1 + e^x))?

The for line 3 -> 4, the sigmoid is 1 / (1 + e^x) and so I understand the sigmoid(x) part of the equation. But how does e^x/(1+e^x) become (1 - sigmoid(x))? Shouldn't it be e^-x / sigmoid(x)?

(I knew all this real well 40 years ago when I earned a math degree, but 40 years of never touching this stuff and all that knowledge is gone...)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you know the chain rule for derivatives?

Comment: @md2perpe I've worked through a refresher and I think I've got the chain rule down. But clearly I'm missing something in it.

Comment: Could you please improve the question by formatting the formulas?

Comment: @md2perpe I am trying to write the formulas using latex, but it's not showing  e^-x with the -x as an exponent. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong in what I wrote (just did the first 2 lines)?

Comment: Write `e^{-x}`.

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you!!!

Comment: @DavidThielen: Over on the meta site, there's a [MathJax/LaTeX cheat sheet](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) that covers many common situations.  Here, in general, the exponentiation symbol takes whatever the next symbol is as its input, unless enclosed in braces.  Hence, for example, `$x^12$` yields $x^12$, while `$x^{12}$` yields $x^{12}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From line $1$ to line $2$: This is an application of the chain rule.  We have

\begin{align}
\sigma'(x) & = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \\
           & = \frac{d}{dx} (1+e^{-x})^{-1} \\
           & = - (1+e^{-x})^{-2} \frac{d}{dx}(1+ e^{-x}) \\
           & = - (-e^{-x}) (1+e^{-x})^{-2} \\
           & = \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}
\end{align}

From line $3$ to line $4$: This is a recognition that

\begin{align}
\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} & = \frac{1+e^{-x}-1}{1+e^{-x}} \\
                        & = 1 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \\
                        & = 1 - \sigma(x)
\end{align}

Comment: I made a slight change to your answer to make clearer the use of the chain rule.

Comment: @jjagmath: Ahh yes, that was not a lack of clarity; that was an actual error!  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not getting 3 -> 4 myself is embarrassing. I think it's going to be a lot more trial and error as I relearn all of this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidThielen: You're welcome!  We've all missed things that we think in retrospect should've been obvious.  But the silver lining is that at least we think it's obvious in retrospect; it's objectively worse if we still don't see it afterward.